# Check if columns have a nan value if certain column has a specific value in Dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to add column in Dataframe which has a result of checking if other columns have value in it.

This is a test df I made:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"condition":[1,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,1],"a":[np.nan,4,5,6,np.nan],"b":[np.nan,2,"e",2,np.nan],"c":[3,2,1,2,np.nan]})
```

So what I want to check is, for each row, if `condition` column's value is `1`, `"b","c","d"` columns should not have values except np.nan. If "condition" has np.nan, result should be "-".

The ideal result should be something like this:

```
    condition    a      b      c     check_result
0    1        np.nan  np.nan    3        "X"
1    np.nan      4      2       2        "-"
2    np.nan      5      "e"     1        "-"
3    np.nan      6      2       2        "-"
4    1        np.nan  np.nan    np.nan   "O"
```

I've tried two ways.

First, this one:

```
def na_and_check(domain,var_list):
    y = ""
    for var in var_list:
        y += '(np.isnan('+domain+'["'+var+'"]))&'
    y = y[:-1]
    print(y)
    return eval(y)

df["check_result"] = np.where(df["condition"]!=1,"-",np.where(na_and_check("df",["a","b","c"]),"O","X"))
```

But since "b" columns has string value in it, it gives me this Error:

```
TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

And for the second one, I tried this:

```
df["check_result"] = np.where(df["condition"]!=1,"-",np.where(df[["a","b","c"]].any(),"X","O"))
```

I wasn't confident with .any() and yes, it gives me an error:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (5,) () (3,)
```

So um... I don't know what to do next.
Any advice or enlightenment, tips will be appreciated. I'll wait for your teach !
Thanks for stopping by. Have a wonderful day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so you have an if-elif-else situation. Then we can use `np.select` for it. It needs the conditions and what to do when they are satisfied:

- your if is:      "condition is 1 and a,b,c has all nan"
- your elif is: "condition is nan"
- what remains is else, as usual

```
conditions = [df.condition.eq(1) & df[["a", "b", "c"]].isna().all(axis=1),
              df.condition.isna()]

what_to_do = ["O", "-"]
else_case = "X"

df["check_result"] = np.select(conditions, what_to_do, default=else_case)

df
```

```
   condition    a    b    c check_result
0        1.0  NaN  NaN  3.0            X
1        NaN  4.0    2  2.0            -
2        NaN  5.0    e  1.0            -
3        NaN  6.0    2  2.0            -
4        1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN            O
```

So we don't write else's condition. It goes to default.

Comment: Oh, let me try this one. I thought np.where is the only if-elif-else one.
Thanks for trimming condition as well!

Comment: yeah np.where is if-else only, this is generalized kind of. you are welcome